# Change order of autocomplete suggestions in PyCharm (args, kwargs before breakpoint when type "ak")

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I use very often shortcut "ak" which autocompletes `*args,**kwargs`. The problem is that it puts `breakpoint(args, kws)` before `*args, **kwargs` suggestion.

I don't use `breakpoint` at all so I want `*args, **kwargs` to be the first (or only) suggestion.

[image: enter code here]

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to achieve that **generally**. If you pay close attention you will note that the suggestions are ordered by the relevance. `breakpoint` is first because you typed `ak`, and `ak` are closer together in `bre ak point` than in `a rgs k wargs`.

However, you can "fix" this by checking "sort suggestions alphabetically" (under settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion). Obviously this will only "fix" this very particular case and will potentially break all other use cases.

Another solution might be removing entries from the code completion dialog (ie remove `breakpoint()`) but I don't think that's possible without other side-effects (eg installing Python < 3.7 where it does not exist).